# What is the best way for perfect forwarding when I know the type passed in

Tags: c++, c++11

If I understand correctly, perfect forwarding uses universal reference to deduce the passed argument is l-value or r-value. It is nice.

That means, to achieve this functionality, I have to make template function.
One possible example can be

```
template <class T>
void func(T&& str){
    auto s = std::forward<T>(str);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

However, what if I know that `T` of `func` should be `std::string` only? I think one possible option is using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` to restrict the type `T`. but it is getting more verbose.

What is the best practice for this kind of situation?

EDIT:

As suggested by Kerrek SB, I am trying to make a possible scenario.

I am making a class which has `std::vector<double>` as a member.
And then, I want to make a constructor which also takes `std::vector<double>`.
If the argument is l-value, I want to copy it to a member, but if not I want to move it.

Is it some kind of possible example?

Comment: Please give a more realistic example. What you describe seems implausible. If you know the argument type, you probably don't want to forward anything. Without further information I'd say pass the string by value or by const-reference.

Comment: I think std::forward<T> should be used in conjunction with constructors only, as the name implies, forwarding possible r-values to constructors of their base class and member variables to prevent "dumb" copying. I'm not sure if there's any other use. Could you please clarify what you intend to do?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I added a possible scenario.

Comment: Okay, so in your example the constructor of std::vector<double> will make sure that T is actually double (implicitly castable to double), otherwise it will generate a compile time error. Do not fear the template :-)

Comment: @rwols no, that's not a good rule of thumb. `std::forward` is useful in many places, not just ctors.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, now that I think about it it it's also used for `std::map::emplace` and such. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a template you have two options:

1. pass by value and move;
2. have one overload for copies and one for moves;

The first option will let the compiler decide between moving or copying into your argument as appropriate. Then your code does not care anymore whether it came from an lvalue or an rvalue (if it came from an lvalue it is already a copy) and moves that into the member. Optimisations aside, this may have the overhead of one move, but if moves are cheap (as is the case with `std::vector`) it may be negligible.

```
foo(std::vector<double> v) : v(std::move(v)) {}
```

With the second option your code makes the decision, instead of the compiler. This avoids the aforementioned possible overhead of one move, but it has the problem of not being scalable: if there are four such parameters that you want to copy or move you would need sixteen different overloads (this exact problem is what perfect forwarding tries to solve).

```
foo(std::vector<double> const& v) : v(v) {}
foo(std::vector<double>&& v) : v(std::move(v)) {}
```

The template option will scale properly but may need some constraining to prevent its use in undesired situations (in the case of an unconstrained template constructor, it can be [mistakenly used for copies](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205121901/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2012/06/05/is_related.html)).

Of course, if you are using types where moves degenerate into copies (like `std::array`), you can just use the first overload of this set.

Comment: first options looks interesting. So you mean that if I pass the r-value to the `foo(std::vector<double> v)`, then no copy is occurred given that the compiler is sufficiently clever right?

Comment: The compiler is required to make that a move.

Comment: I don't see any advantages in 2. You will need to needlessly duplicate code and from a user's perspective it behaves *exactly* as 1. I don't think the distinction between 'compiler decides' vs. 'user code decides' makes sense here. And worrying about an additional move is just silly imho ;)

Comment: @ComicSansMS "And worrying about an additional move is just silly imho ;)" and "it behaves *exactly* as 1." are contradictory. Either they behave *exactly* the same or there is an additional move to be silly about. Which is it?

Comment: And considering additional *expensive* moves (those do exist) is not silly.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Expensive moves do exist, but they are a few and far between and often a consequence of bad design. Also, the compiler might eat the second move anyway. I see the validity of mentioning that possibility, but it should be pointed out as exceptional. And I still insist on the argument that from a user's perspective the interfaces behave the same. There is no benefit in 2. except for implementation details that can be communicated more clearly to a user than with an overloaded constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Pass it by value.

That case the user decides whether he wants his end of the vector to be destroyed or not. It also will work as expected when the argument is clearly an rvalue (e.g. when constructing the vector as a temporary inside the function call). Perfect forwarding is the wrong tool here.